# How does one configure a battery whem compiling Linux

Tags: linux, battery

Compiling Linux on a CPU : RockChip RK3326(Quad-Core ARM 64bit Cortex-A35 1.3GHz).

Where what I enter the battery full charge data?  The battery is just a lipo with a charge controller.

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific at which point which part of the process needs the data from you.

Answer (score 0):

This is something provided by another chip and not software.  Therefore I cannot set it without changing the data in that chip.

Thanks all.